# laravel users with several roles having several permissions

Tags: laravel, middleware, access-control, rbac

I want to create a RBAC system in laravel where a user can belong to several roles, and each role can have several permissions. The middleware should check if the user has a certain permission (within any of their roles) before it continues with the request.

I am able to implement a case where

- A user belongs to one role which has many permissions
- A user belongs to several roles which are used to determine access control (without the permissions bit)

I need to implement a user with multiple roles having multiple permissions. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you show an overview of what you've implemented so far i.e. db table, eloquent relationships, how you're performing the checks etc.?

Comment: what about spatie or laratrust package?!

Comment: Use attribute-based access control ([tag:abac]) or like @IsmoilShifoev said, use existing laravel packages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not interested in coding this yourself the a package like Laravel permissions would do exactly what you want.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

Otherwise you need to create pivot tables between the users ans their roles and the roles and their permissions

So you would have a user_roles table that would consist of user_id and role_I'd.

You would also have a role_permissions table which would have role_id and permission_id.

This would allow you to have many to many relationship and have many through relationship to get straight from user to role and role to user.

Hope that helps

Comment: i did this, but the middleware returns an error Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckRole::handle(), 2 passed in /Library/WebServer/Documents/gmoney/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 151 and exactly 3 expected"

Comment: am using the middleware in api.php

Comment: @muoki_D I am going to need more details. Can you please post your code so that we can view it?

Answer (score 0):

As an overview. You need to have a `roles` table in your database which defines different types of user's your application can have , Like (Admin, Author, Editor, Moderator etc)

You also need to define a table `role_user` which contains data on which user has which role. This will be a Many to Many relationship since a user can have multiple roles.

Next you need to define a Middleware `CheckRole` which basically checks if user has a particular role. You can use this Middleware on different parts of your application to restrict authentication.

You might find this tutorial useful :

https://www.5balloons.info/user-role-based-authentication-and-access-control-in-laravel/

Comment: Avoid implementing access control from scratch and use existing tooling